# Converting Label outputs (string,int,float)

Tags: python, tkinter

Iam relatively new to python and I've been trying to make a "software" with turtle and tkinter libraries, where the goal is to draw a polygon with n sides where n is the entry input in a label. Theres also a simple button which basically initiates the whole process. I've got to a point where i need to define u as the angle, whereas u=360/n;however i keep getting this error:

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`
or
`unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'StringVar`

I've tried converting the output of the label to both float or int types of information, however I can't quite seem to figure it out. How should I proceed with converting the output from the entry? Any help is much appreciated and I wish anyone reading this a pleasant rest of the day.
Here is the code so far:

```
import turtle
import random
#################
canv=tkinter.Canvas(width=400,height=400)
canv.pack()
#################
tcanv=turtle.TurtleScreen(canv)
t=turtle.RawTurtle(tcanv)


n=tkinter.StringVar()
label=tkinter.Label(text="Sides?")
label.pack()
entry=tkinter.Entry(textvariable="n")
entry.pack()


u=(360/n) if n != 0 else 0

def draw():
    for i in range (n):
        t.fd(50)
        t.left(u)

btn=tkinter.Button (text="Draw",fg="black",command=Draw)
btn.pack()
label.mainloop()
entry.mainloop()
btn.mainloop()
```

Comment: It should be a variable, like `textvariable=n` and also initially `n` is empty, meaning it is `''` so you need to give it some time to type. So put it inside a function or delay it a bit, till you enter the input

Comment: And may I ask what is the simplest way to delay it? What came first to my mind is ```time.sleep()```,however I can't seem to find a way to implement it as of now as I dont know for how long should I delay it and I dont know how to delay something till something happens if you know what I mean.

Comment: `time.sleep()` will freeze the GUI, use `after()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems with your usage of tkinter, I suggest you try following [some guide](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-3-tkinter-basics-tutorial/) first.

For your code, try this:

```py
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def draw():
    n = int(entry.get())
    u = (360 / n) if n != 0 else 0
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(50)
        t.left(u)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    canv = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
    canv.pack()

    tcanv = turtle.TurtleScreen(canv)
    t = turtle.RawTurtle(tcanv)

    label = tk.Label(root, text="Sides?")
    label.pack()

    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack()

    btn = tk.Button(text="Draw", fg="black", command=draw)
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

(Only reordered your code and changed the string var)